# RDS SQL Server compression

Tags: sql-server, compression, rds

I have few Clarification regarding AWS RDS SQL Server.

1. Do we have any compression technique to compress the data loaded into RDS SQL server?
2. Is there any option or parameter to compress the data and load into RDS SQL server?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Moved to DBA stackexchange